# Raspberry Pi CM does not start

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux

I designed a motherboard for RPi Compute Module (v1). The compute module is flashed with Raspbian and I confirm that I can see the root console on its pins (GPIO14 and GPIO15) when plugged into its official motherboard (CMIO).

Now when it is plugged into mine it does not do anything.

Things I have checked so far:

- 3.3V, 2.5V and 1.8V are super precious and they are generated by the same components as it was on the CMIO board and the original RPi version 1.
- When powered there is no power consumption from the main source which is 5V.
- On the serial console there is no activity at all.

My motherboard is very simple, but at the moment there is only the power supplies and the RPi CM header are soldered.
In the datasheet of the CM it looks that it only needs power.

Now what would you recommend me to investigate? I'm quite stuck on this issue now.

Datasheet: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf

Comment: Sounds like you probably missed something - go over the pins one by one and make sure they have what they should.  Look at enables for the regulators.  And make sure that no pinout (of the module, regulator, etc) ended up accidentally flipped or re-numbered.  This isn't really an answerable question within the mission of this site, which is limited to specific, fully documented questions.

Comment: With no power consumption I would start with VBAT and RUN.

Comment: RUN has an internal 10k pullup. I left it unconnected. All the power rails are fine and can be measured on the correct pins of the CM.

Comment: Make a schematic of your board showing connections to the compute module. The CM has 6 power supply pins which should be powered up in a particular order, and saying "3.3V, 2.5V and 1.8V are super precious" [sic] doesn't convince me this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the HDMI - the RPi bootloader is run by the GPU. On HDMI there is a hotplug pin which needs a pullup resistor. If the pullup is not present the bootloader won't run - I guess the GPU gets stuck trying to talk to the nonexistent device.

Also make sure that your power supply sequencing is correct - highest voltage should be on first.

Comment: That would be seriously good point, thank you. Since I did not need HDMI, I did't connect anything to it.
However in the datasheet on page 12, there is a table (Table 3) which recommends leaving open each run & boot control pin if unused, and the same applies to all HDMI pins.
Could you clarify please which pin would need the pullup?
Power sequencing should not be any problem, I have a 100k + 100nF RC on the 1.8V enable. So I think 3.3V rail comes up first (along with 2.5V for TVDAC) and then a bit later comes the 1.8V rail.

Comment: @Daniel then check it. Also verify it with the CMIO schematics.

Comment: My design is more or less based on the CMIO schematics. However every document writes that I don't need any specific pullup/pulldown anywhere except GPIO28,29,44,45 since they don't have internal pu/pd.
Are you referring to GPIO46_1V8?

Comment: @Daniel the point about HDMI is actually from experience and the HDMI spec does require that hotplug pullup AFAIR. It's a settop box processor so HDMI not being present most likely was not considered when designing BCM2835.

Comment: Understood. So this hotplug pin is GPIO46_1V8 if I'm not mistaken. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CMIO-V1_2-SCHEMATIC.pdf (second page, bottom-right corner)
It is pullled to 1.8V if there is no device attached to the HDMI. Am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel seems so looking at CMIO schematics. If that does not work pull up also CEC, SDA and SCL. Simply put even if you dont use HDMI make sure those four control lines behave as if it was used but no device is present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74194/discussion-between-daniel-and-jan-dorniak).